# How to get a sort order from wildcard property name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My JSON object looks like this and I want to sort them based on property starting with `sort_`

```
{    
    "sort_11832": "1",    
    "productsId": [
        "11832",
        "160",
        "180"
    ],    
    "sort_160": "0",
    "sort_180": "2"
}
```

Ideally I would like to get a result of ids based on sort order like this -

```
[ "160","18832","180" ]
```

Any suggestion on how to sort by wildcard property name. Using Javascript/Jquery ofcourse.

Comment: Why in heaven's name would anything produce data like that? It's absurd.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried? Right now, this reads as "please write this sorting code for me."

Comment: Also a JS object is not ordered. You may get the data out in the order you put it in but it is not a given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone. It was a daft way of approaching this. Point taken and I have now changed the data set to something like this which makes everything very easier -

```
sort: [
{
    \"id\": \"160\",
    \"sort\": 0
},
{
    \"id\": \"11832\",
    \"sort\": 1


   }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'd do:

- Go back to whatever is producing that truly absurd data and have them just return an array in the correct order in the first place, rather than producing an array and then repeating all the entries as separate properties with `sort_` in front of them and a number.

Very, very, very, very far down in second place if the above weren't successful, I'd do this:

- Call [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) on the array, passing in a comparator function
- In the comparator function, put `"sort_"` in front of each of the two values the function was given to compare, and use that property name to look up the the numeric string for that property in the object
- Parse those two numeric strings into numbers
- Return the result of subtracting the second one's number from the first

Code is left as an exercise to the reader.